# SQLite how to replace NULL with string 'default'

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm using SQLite and python
I have a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM TRANSACTIONS
LEFT JOIN HQITS_PRJ_TAGS ON UPPER(TRANSACTIONS.tags) = UPPER(HQITS_PRJ_TAGS.project_tag)
WHERE TRANSACTIONS.id = ?
```

If there isn't a match in the `HQITS_PRJ_TAGS` table then the fetchall() method returns `None` for the columns from the `HQITS_PRJ_TAGS` table.

What I want to do is instead of `None` I want to return a 'default' string.

I tried looking into the `COALESCE` command but I did not manage to get it to work.

Here is what is returned by the above query:

```
{'id': 'd5c8fe96241e776fff742e0719b06c48', 'date': '2023-07-18', 'amount': '-8', 'currency': 'GBP', 'account': 'Card', 'bank': 'American Express', 'category': 'Transport', 'type': 'Purchase', 'tags': 'Ldf', 'counterparty': 'CHARGE', 'custom_name': '', 'merchant': 'Ldf', 'additional_details': '', 'notes': '', 'linked_transaction_id': '', 'account_name': 'Card', 'account_family': 'Name', 'project_name': None, 'client_name': None, 'project_tag': None}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You're missing to show your sample data, your current result and the expected result. It's also unknown what method "fetchall()" you talk about. Your query doesn't contain such method. COALESCE can replace NULL by other values, not None. Why do you get None, not NULL? This sounds very strange. In this case, you would need to replace it, COALESCE can't do that.

Comment: For which of your columns do you get "None"? Using * is very bad practice, especially when fetching data from multiple tables. You will do better to name the columns (with table alias to rule out exceptions) which should be selected.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I want all the columns from both the tables, there are like 16 columns in the main `TRANSACTIONS` table and 6 columns in the `HQITS_PRJ_TAGS` which one of them is linked back to the`TRANSACTIONS` table, but not all the rows in the `TRANSACTIONS` table have a match in the `HQITS_PRJ_TAGS` table

Comment: Please allow people here to understand and reproduce your issue. Keep in mind we don't have access to your DB, we don't even see your screen. You could create a fiddle and share the link, for example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/vRbqFpk_ Or at least provide sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I've added the dictionary that is returned by the query, if you look at the last 3 keys, are coming from the JOIN table, as there is no match in the JOIN table they are returned as `None` - I would like them to be an empty string instead. If you look at some of the values in the main table are stored as empty string when the value is n/a so the issue here is that when i JOIN the table if there is no match the values for the JOIN table keys are returned as `None`

Comment: Sorry, I can't help without further information (see previous comments). You could try to add COALESCE for all nullable columns, meaning SELECT COALESCE(nullableColumn1,'default'), notnullColumn1, COALESCE(nullableColumn2,'default')...FROM...But I have no idea whether this will solve your issue. You will need to provide a fiddle or have much luck that someone will tell you what your issue is by nearly pure guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I am interpreting your question correctly but:

No need to do this in sqlite, you can just use python.

```
result = [execute your query...]
result = result if result else 'default'
```

Comment: to do that I will need to iterate through each of the records returned by the fetchall() and check if any of the values inside the record is `None` then convert it to `'default'`. It would be cleaner if the sql query could return the default string instead of the `None` value

Comment: Maybe, but that's not how SQL works.  Unmatched columns in a JOIN get the NULL value.  Just deal with it in code.